# (Another) problem with url hyphenation in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, hyphenation, urls

What I am about to ask has already been asked many times, but nothing seems to work for me so far. Basically I am having troubles in getting urls hyphenated correctly in the bibliography.

I modified the command `\UrlBreaks` so that it allows hyphenation everywhere, but this seems to be ignored in the bibliography, while in the rest of the document it does work.

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true,sorting=nty]{biblatex}%
\usepackage[breaklinks,plainpages=false]{hyperref}%
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do0\do1\do2\do3\do4\do5\do6\do7\do8\do9\do=\do/\do.\do:}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{citation} for further details or visit \url{http://www.joifewoirjecpwoirjcpewrijcpenwrjcpnewrjicpnwerjincpejricpejripcne.com}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the references are in the file Biblio.bib as follows

```
@book{citation,
author = {Doe, John},
title = {The Book},
url = {http://www.joifewoirjecpwoirjcpewrijcpenwrjcpnewrjicpnwerjincpejricpejripcne.com}
}
```

Compiling with `xelatex` (or `pdflatex`) and `bibtex` results in the following output:
[image: Compiled with xelatex]

**A curiosity** (hope it helps in finding the bug): the image above is what comes out compiling with `xelatex`; compiling with `pdflatex` gives the same output, except for the cyan countour line of the link which, ironically, *gets hyphenated*:
[image: Compiled with latex]

Using `\sloppy` does something better, but still doesn't make the links hyphenate where I want, i.e. anywhere:
[image: With sloppy option]

As you may imagine, `\raggedright` doesn't solve the issue either.

What I am looking for is some code that allows a good hyphenation of the urls in the bibliography with these constraints (I don't know if they are relevant):

1. it has to work with `xelatex` and `bibtex` (`backend=biber` option to `biblatex` doesn't work for me somehow)
2. package `polyglossia` must not be required, rather it has to work with `babel`
3. compatible with package `hyperref`
4. compatible with `book` document class

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`biblatex` has a number of counters which when set to non-zero positive values less than `10000` allow breaks in urls in the bibliography.  The specific counters are

```
biburlnumpenalty
biburlucpenalty
biburllcpenalty
```

for breaks after numbers, uppercase letters and lowercase letters, respectively.  In your case it suffices to set the lowercase penalty to `9000`; lower values encourage breaks more (or rather discourage them less).  The setting is done value via `\setcounter`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,a4paper]{article}%
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true,sorting=nty]{biblatex}%
\usepackage[breaklinks,plainpages=false]{hyperref}%
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z\do0\do1\do2\do3\do4\do5\do6\do7\do8\do9\do=\do/\do.\do:}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{citation} for further details or visit \url{http://www.joifewoirjecpwoirjcpewrijcpenwrjcpnewrjicpnwerjincpejricpejripcne.com}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When choosing values for these penalties it is useful to note that `biblatex`'s defaults are

```
\UrlBigBreakPenalty   100
```

for breaks after `:` and `-`, and

```
\UrlBreakPenalty      200
```

for breaks after most punctuation characters.  You want to set the other penalties significantly higher, so that breaks after numbers and letters are of a lower prioriy than those after punctuation marks.  If you need to change the two `\Url...BreakPenalty`s above then it is via the unusual syntax of

```
\mathchardef\UrlBreakPenalty=200\relax
```