# Page numbers are still too deep, even with the option onpsinit = {\linespread{1}\selectfont}

Tags: koma-script, geometry

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442308/how-to-adjust-the-breaking-in-the-bibliography).

I have to use weird margins and line spacing for my academic writing. MWE:

```
\documentclass[
               pagesize,
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV = calc% for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40
% for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40:
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\KOMAoptions{
             DIV = last,
             onpsinit = {\linespread{1}\selectfont}% slightly heaves the page numbers
            }

\begin{document}

  Test.

\end{document}
```

The result:
[image: page numbers]
Can I have more control of the position of the page numbers? At least one line height of space should be below of the page numbers!

Thank you for your help and effort in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Do not use `DIV=last` after your `geometry` settings. This KOMA-Script option recalculates the typearea! Load package `showframe` or use the geometry option `showframe` to see the difference. Eg. left and right margin will have the same width again.

Load package `setspace` with option `onehalfspacing` before the `geometry settings`. Then you can use geometry options `heightrounded` and `footskip=<length>`.

Since KOMA-Script version 3.24 (current is 3.25) there is an option `singlespacing` for `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV=calc
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% before the geometry settings

\usepackage[
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm,
            includehead,% remove if the header should be inside the 20mm top margin
            heightrounded,
            footskip=30pt% <- adjust to your needs
           ]{geometry}

\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

% the following packages are only for this example:
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{layout}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\layout%  to show the page layout

Test.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that KOMA-Script option `pagesize` is default. If you remove both options `usegeometry=on` and `DIV=calc` in the example above only `\marginparwidth` changes.

---

It is also possible to shift all layers in the footer of `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. If the bottom of these layers should be 2\baselineskips above of lower page border, you can use

```
\documentclass[
               usegeometry = on,
               DIV=calc
              ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% before the geometry settings

\usepackage[
            left = 25mm,
            bottom = 20mm,
            right = 45mm,
            top = 20mm,
            includehead,% remove if the header should be inside the 20mm top margin
            heightrounded,
           ]{geometry}

\usepackage[singlespacing]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{scrheadings}{%
    \ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}
      {\ModifyLayer[voffset=\paperheight-2\baselineskip,align=b]{#1}}
      {}%
}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle*{plain.scrheadings}{%
    \ifstrstart{#1}{plain.scrheadings.foot}
      {\ModifyLayer[voffset=\paperheight-3\baselineskip,align=b]{#1}}
      {}%
}
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

% the following packages are only for this example:
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{layout}% to show the page layout

\begin{document}
\layout%  to show the page layout

Test.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello @esdd! Thank you for this great solution! Now the margins are finally like like expected. However there is an another [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442620/page-number-of-a-page-with-landscape-layout-not-visible) now, which doesn't appierd before. Could you please help with it.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use for example command

```
\setlength{\footskip}{0.75cm}
```

to define the distance of the last groundline of text to first groundline of foot. Change the value to your needs ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  pagesize,
  usegeometry = on,
  DIV = calc,        % for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[%
  left = 25mm,
  bottom = 20mm,
  right = 45mm,
  top = 20mm,
  showframe % <=========================================================
]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}% for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40
% for the line spacing, KOMA-Script manual, page 40:
\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\KOMAoptions{%
  DIV = last,
  onpsinit = {\linespread{1}\selectfont}% slightly heaves the page numbers
}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.75cm} % <=======================================


\begin{document}

Test.

\end{document}
```

you get the result (see that I used option `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins):

[image]

Comment: `geometry` also has an option `footskip`.