# How do I use certain characters as preferred for line breaks with xurl?

Tags: xurl

`xurl` is a great solution.

Here is a quote from the pramble:

> Package xurl loads package url by default and defines possible url
> breaks for all alphanumerical characters and = / . : * - ~ ' "

How do I add underscore = / . : * - ~ ' " and _ as ***preferred*** characters to break the following `url`

```
https://www.weibull.com/pubs/2011_RAMS_planning_a_reliability_growth_program_utilizing_historical_data.pdf
```

It should only break words as a last resort.

Minimal code showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xurl}
\begin{document}
Here is the url \url{https://www.weibull.com/pubs/2011_RAMS_planning_a_reliability_growth_program_utilizing_historical_data.pdf}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `xurl` is set up to line-break a URL string at *all* characters, *including* `_` (underscore) characters. Are you maybe asking how to line-break the URL *only* at underscore characters?

Comment: Did you actually use `\url` to typeset the URL in question? As Mico says, `xurl` allows line breaks in `\url` after all characters, so in particular after `_`. If that's not what you are seeing, something is up. (All of this URL line breaking relies on TeX knowing it is a URL. So the `\url{...}` macro is essential.) Note that even with the standard settings of `url`, a line break is allowed after `_`, so for this URL you may not even need `xurl`, `url` might be enough.

Comment: @Mico and moewe, see example added.  The minimal code example shows that underscores are not used as line-breaks, at least not in Overleaf.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want linebreaks to *only*  occur at a `_`?

Comment: @skvery - I compiled your program both on Overleaf and on MacTeX2020. In both cases, a line break occurs before "am" in "program". The result looks *just fine* to me. The likelihood of a line break in this URL string occurring between two letters rather than after an underscore character is very high ex ante, given that only 8 out of the 98 characters of the URL string (not counting the `https://` prefix) are underscores. As @moewe and I have been wont to point out to you, the whole point of the `xurl` package is to let line breaks occur *anywhere* in the argument of `\url`.

Comment: @Mico I expected the break to occur next to a underscore, not in the middle of a word, but I understand now after testing with dash instead of underscore.

Comment: @Mico  I also added the preamble from the xurl package and added a sentence to clarify my question.

Comment: @skvery - So, basically, you're looking for something *completely different* from what the `xurl` package is designed for. You should say so up front.

Answer (score 4):

In theory it is possible to allow line breaks after `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9` in `\url` in addition to other possible break points, but with a higher penalty (which means LaTeX will prefer other hyphenation points).

I have my doubts that this will have an effect that is significantly different from just loading `xurl`, which allows breaks everywhere with the same penalty, though. If a URL takes up a significant portion of the line, chances are there is little space left to shrink and enlarge, which means that TeX has little leeway in deciding where exactly to break the line: Either the URL can be broken pretty much where it meets the margin or not.

Anyway, here is how `biblatex` does it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mathchardef\UrlNotSoGreatBreakPenalty=800 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begingroup
\def\do#1{%
  \gappto\UrlSpecials{%
    \do#1{%
      \mathchar`#1
      \penalty\UrlNotSoGreatBreakPenalty}}}
\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J
  \do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T
  \do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z
\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z
\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0
\endgroup


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Text \url{https://www.weibull.com/pubs/2011_RAMS_planning_a_reliability_growth_program_utilizing_historical_data.pdf}.

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Broken URL]

This assigns a penalty of 800 to not so great breaks after `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`. Breaks after punctuation has penalty 700, big breaks after `:` a penalty of 500.

---

You could allow some stretchable space as suggested in [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467048/35864) to ['Uneven' breaks in long URLs (\url)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467041/35864) (which has already been shamelessly stolen by `biblatex`: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/850, https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/886). This may make it possible to allow your URLs to break in nicer places at the cost of some more whitespace between characters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\mathchardef\UrlNotSoGreatBreakPenalty=800 

\newmuskip\urlalnumskip
\setlength{\urlalnumskip}{0mu plus 2mu}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begingroup
\def\do#1{%
  \gappto\UrlSpecials{%
    \do#1{%
      \mathchar`#1
      \mskip\urlalnumskip
      \penalty\UrlNotSoGreatBreakPenalty}}}
\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J
  \do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T
  \do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z
\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z
\do\1\do\2\do\3\do\4\do\5\do\6\do\7\do\8\do\9\do\0
\endgroup


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Text \url{https://www.weibull.com/pubs/2011_RAMS_planning_a_reliability_growth_program_utilizing_historical_data.pdf}.

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicely broken, but spaced URL.]

Note how the characters in the first line are spaced out quite a bit to make the nicer break possible.

If you play around with the penalty and the stretchable space you will find that the penalty only has a real effect if the stretchable space can give it enough leeway.

Answer (score 3):

This creates a `\url` command that allows breaks at specified characters, here given as `/`, `.`, and `_`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\catcode`_=12 
\newcommand{\url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\penalty0 }%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\penalty0 }%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{_\penalty0 }%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`.=\active\catcode`_=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\catcode`_=8 
\begin{document}
Here is the url \url{https://www.weibull.com/pubs/2011_RAMS_planning_a_reliability_growth_program_utilizing_historical_data.pdf}.
\end{document}
```

[image]