# Biblatex date field causing "Overfull \hbox"

Tags: biblatex

One of my `biblatex` entries causing a `Overfull \hbox` message. The result looks like this

[image]

The question is how I could handle errors like this? Removing the `date`/`eventdate` field or shorten the title is not possible.

This is the mwe for the result above.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InProceedings{Paulicke2019a,
  author       = {Denny Paulicke and Christian Buhtz and Karsten Schwarz and Katrin Wedler and Dietrich Stoevesandt and Patrick Jahn},
  title        = {Technische Assistenzsysteme in der Pflegeausbildung},
  subtitle     = {Eine Online-Erhebung},
  eventtitle   = {20. Jahrestagung EbM-Netzwerk 2019 - EbM und digitale Transformation in der Medizin},
  eventdate    = {2019-03-22},
  venue        = {Berlin},
  organization = {Deutschen Netzwerks Evidenzbasierte Medizin e. V. (DNEbM)},
  publisher    = {German Medical Science GMS Publishing House},
  doi          = {10.3205/19ebm059},
  eprint       = {nbn:de:0183-19ebm0591},
  eprinttype   = {urn},
  year         = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=apa,
    sortlocale=auto,
    language=german
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's tricky. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 for possible options.

Comment: In your example `\begingroup
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0.7em}
\printbibliography
\endgroup` would work and gives (just about) acceptable output. But you could also go full `\RaggedRight` (courtesy of `\usepackage{ragged2e}`). Just two things: I would use an en-dash `--` in the `eventtitle` and not just a single hyphen (`-`) to separate the second part. In `e. V.` you may want to check out if you prefer the version with a small (unbreakable!) space: `e.\,V.` especially for due to the `V` the thin space looks a bit nicer in my opinion.