# How to prevent bibliography from ugly line breaks?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I often get the same issue. Only two letters move to the next line. Is there a way to make this look better? e.g. by using a blockset in which ISBN numbers are not splitted?

I already tried to add some spaces into title or I used \text{} etc. There was no improvement.

[image]

Edit:
Sorry, I thought there is an easy solution. I use biblatex and I have to use a template - means: manually edited bibliography

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 

\setlength\bibhang{1cm} 

%%% Weitere Optionen 
%\boolitem[false]{citexref} %Wenn incollection, inbook, inproceedings genutzt wird nicht den zugehörigen parent auch in Literaturverzeichnis aufnehmen

%Aufräumen die Felder werden laut Leitfaden nicht benötigt.
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{issn}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{isbn}%
    \clearfield{url}
    \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{collection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{incollection}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{article}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
\ifentrytype{inproceedings}{
  \clearfield{issn}%
  \clearfield{doi}%
  \clearfield{isbn}%
  \clearfield{url}
  \clearfield{eprint}
}{}
}

\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}%Kein Punkt am ende des Literaturverzeichnisses

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 
\DeclareDelimFormat{titleyeardelim}{\newunitpunct} 
%Namen kursiv schreiben
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}{\mkbibemph} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}{\mkbibemph} 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}{\mkbibemph} 
%Delimiter für mehrere und letzten Namen gleich setzen
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\addspace}%hinzugefügt. Ansonsten werden mehrere namen mit komma getrennt
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim} 

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given} 
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}  %Nach Namen sortieren


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace} 
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{innametitledelim}{\addcomma\space} 

\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1} 

\xpatchbibdriver{online} 
  {\usebibmacro{organization+location+date}\newunit\newblock} 
  {} 
  {}{} 

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{date}{\mkbibparens{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{#1\addspace Uhr}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%urltime zu urldate hinzufügen
  [Zugriff\addcolon\addspace
  #1
  \printfield{urltime}]
}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space <\url{#1}>}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{% 
  \usebibmacro{url}% 
  \ifentrytype{online} 
    {\setunit*{\addspace}% 
     \iffieldundef{year}
       {\printtext[date]{keine Datumsangabe}} 
       {\usebibmacro{date}}}% 
    {}% 
  \setunit*{\addspace}% 
  \usebibmacro{urldate}
  } 


\renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{% 
  \printtext[parens]{% 
    \printfield{usera}% 
    \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}% 
    \printlabeldateextra}} 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{ 
  nodate    = {{}o.\adddot J\adddot}, 
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot} 
} 

\DeclareSourcemap{ 
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{ 
    \map{ 
      \step[notfield=translator, final] 
      \step[notfield=editor, final] 
      \step[fieldset=author, fieldvalue={{{o\noexpand\adddot V\noexpand\adddot}}}] 
    } 
    \map{ 
      \pernottype{online} 
      \step[fieldset=location, fieldvalue={o\noexpand\adddot O\noexpand\adddot}] 
    } 
  } 
} 

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{% 
  \iffieldundef{shorthand} 
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}} 
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}% 
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonametitledelim}}} 
       {\printnames{labelname}% 
        \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}% 
     \printfield{usera}% 
     \setunit{\printdelim{titleyeardelim}}% 
     \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}} 
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}} 

    \renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\addspace}% Trennung zwischen journalname und Volume. Sonst Space; Laut Leitfaden richtig
    \hypersetup{hidelinks} %sonst sind Fußnoten grün. Dadurch werden Links allerdings nicht mehr farbig dargestellt

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \iffieldundef{volume}
    {}
    {\printfield{volume}}
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
  {}
  {
  (\thefield{year}) %Ansonsten wird wenn kein Volume angegeben ist ein Komma vorangestellt
  }
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace Nr\adddot\addcolon\addspace}
  \printfield{number}
  \iffieldundef{eid}
  {}
  {\printfield{eid}}
}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{% 
  \setunit{\postnotedelim}% 
  \iffieldundef{postnote} 
    {\printtext{o.S\adddot}} 
    {\printfield{postnote}}}
```

and this file

```
% Opptionen für Biblatex
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
giveninits=false,
isbn=true,
url=true,
doi=false,
eprint=false,
maxbibnames=7, % Alle Autoren (kein et al.)
maxcitenames=2, % et al. ab dem 3. Autor
backref=false, % Rückverweise auf Zitatseiten
bibencoding=utf8, % wenn .bib in utf8, sonst ascii
bibwarn=true, % Warnung bei fehlerhafter bib-Datei
}%

% et al. an Stelle von u.a.
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

% Klammern um das Jahr in der Fußnote
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \mkbibparens{%
         \printfield{labelyear}%
         \printfield{extrayear}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printdate}}

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
  \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}
    }
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}
    }%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

% Alternative Notation der Fußnoten
% Zeigt sowohl den Nachnamen als auch den Vornamen an
% Beispiel: \fullfootcite[Vgl. ][Seite 5]{Tanenbaum.2003}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullfootcite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printnames[sortname][1-1]{author}%
    \addspace (\printfield{year})}
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

%Autoren (Nachname, Vorname)
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

%Reihenfolge von publisher, year, address verändern
% Achtung, bisher nur für den Typ @book definiert

%% Definiert @Book Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\addcolon\space
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \newunit\newblockpunct
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{isbn}%
  \finentry}

%% Definiert @Online Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblockpunct
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{url}%
  \setunit*{,\space Erscheinungsjahr:\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit*{,\space Zugriff am:\space}%
  \printfield{note}%
  \finentry}

%% Definiert @Article Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \newunit\newblockpunct
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit*{.\space In:\space}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{volume}\newunit{}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{year}\newunit{}%
  \setunit*{,\space Nr.\space}%
  \printfield{number}\newunit{}%
  \setunit*{,\space}%
  \printfield{pages}\newunit{}%
  \finentry}

%% Definiert @InProceedings Eintrag
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
    \printnames{author}%
    \setunit*{,\space (}%
    \printfield{year}\newunit{)}%
    \newunit\newblockpunct
    \printfield{title}%
    \setunit*{\space}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{,\space}%
    \printfield{publisher}%
    \setunit*{,\space}%
    \printfield{isbn}%
    %\setunit*{,\space}%
    %\printfield{doi}%
    \finentry}

%Doppelpunkt nach dem letzten Autor
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace }

%Komma an Stelle des Punktes
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

%Autoren durch Semikolon trennen
\newcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\newcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \let\multinamedelim\bibmultinamedelim
  \let\finalnamedelim\bibfinalnamedelim
}

%Titel nicht kursiv anzeigen
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
```

Comment: This will depend on how you make the bibilography - do you use `biblatex`? `natbib`? Manually edited `thebibliography` environment? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: Have you tried setting the Bibliography `\raggedright` ?

Comment: I think the break in the ISBN is the least bad option. But in general line breaking is hard. I wrote up something on that over in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864. I should mention that the `biblatex` modifications from your file seem to be of varying quality: Some of it is using very up to date code, while others is unnecessary, not very elegant or outright wrong.