# BibLaTeX Bibiliography - Justified text

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, german, justification

I use the ngerman-package of babel in the main text part of my thesis and could manage to achieve a completely justified text by adding `\usepackage{microtype}`

In the bibliography the justification is violated. In order to justify items including URLs I managed to do so by setting a penalty: `\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{8000}`

But in order to do so with item-titles too I only found `\hyphenation{Lou-is-i-ana}`
Is there already any more modern aproach and I just fail to find it?

Comment: Hard to say without a concrete example (a compilable, yet minimal document that reproduces the bad line breaking, not just a picture of it), but in general line breaking is hard and it may be double hard in bibliographies. I listed some common causes of bad breaks and some strategies in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864.

Comment: @moewe -- Really nice linked answer.  An observation that you might consider adding: geographical names are often not hyphenated at all (not usually as long as urls, but almost equally bad).  Known instances are listed in the TUGboat hyphenation exception list, and posted on CTAN in the `hyphenex` collection.  ("Louisiana" is in the list of needed additions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good point. Thank you. I have slightly reworded the section about "tricky words" to make it more general and added the example about geographic names.

Comment: Any news here? As I mentioned in the first comment without a concrete example it is hard to say more. If the question remains as-is I will probably vote to close as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864, because the answer there describes several (specific and general) ways to fix/improve line breaking in the bibliography.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate. If you want more specific advice I suggest you ask a new question with an example document that reproduces the problematic output.