# weird space between url and https, using \bibliography (bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, texlive, white-space, url

currently, I'm preparing my references using \bibliography{mybibfile} and at the beginning, the URL was too long in my references.
[image]
 So, I found that I should use:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

then I realized there is a wide space between the URL and the address.
[image]
Then I tried the other method:

```
\begingroup
\raggedright
\bibliography{second_paper2}
\endgroup
```

But it only keeps the URL and http in one line and the rest of it in the next line.
[image]
I also tried to change the bib file from:

```
@article{wanunu_dna_2008,
    title = {{DNA} {Translocation} {Governed} by {Interactions} with {Solid}-{State} {Nanopores}},
    volume = {95},
    issn = {00063495},
    url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0006349508786107},
    doi = {10.1529/biophysj.108.140475},
    language = {en},
    number = {10},
    urldate = {2018-07-09},
    journal = {Biophysical Journal},
    author = {Wanunu, Meni and Sutin, Jason and McNally, Ben and Chow, Andrew and Meller, Amit},
    month = nov,
    year = {2008},
    pages = {4716--4725}
}
```

to this (using the \url):

```
@article{wanunu_dna_2008,
    title = {{DNA} {Translocation} {Governed} by {Interactions} with {Solid}-{State} {Nanopores}},
    volume = {95},
    issn = {00063495},
    note = {\url{http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0006349508786107}},
    doi = {10.1529/biophysj.108.140475},
    language = {en},
    number = {10},
    urldate = {2018-07-09},
    journal = {Biophysical Journal},
    author = {Wanunu, Meni and Sutin, Jason and McNally, Ben and Chow, Andrew and Meller, Amit},
    month = nov,
    year = {2008},
    pages = {4716--4725}
}
```

But only remove the URL and place the http adress before DOI which is wrong.
This is my code:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,graphicx,amsmath,setspace,bm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
something\cite{ren_numerical_2016,cao_translocation_2015,wanunu_dna_2008}.

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\section*{\refname}

\bibliography{second_paper2}
\end{document}
```

I use pdflatex and bibtex. Do you have any idea how i can fix this?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you tried loading `xurl` instead of `url`? It allows URLs to be broken at arbitrary places.

Comment: Basically there are not enough break points in your url. You can try the xurl package which allows an url to break almost everywhere. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442308/how-to-adjust-the-breaking-in-the-bibliography

Comment: changing from url to xurl worked perfectly.  thank you so much.