# Biblatex + kpfonts = unclean line breaks?

Tags: biblatex, kpfonts

I am using biblatex and biber to create the bibliography of my thesis. I am also using kpfonts.

I noticed that in almost every entry of my bibliography there is one line in which a symbol or letter extends over the right border. Take a look:

[image]

This problem only occurs in the bibliography section of the document, all normal text paragraphs have proper edges. The problem also does not occur when I am not using kpfonts.

Therefore I am concluding that the problem lays in the interplay of biblatex with kpfonts. Probably biblatex is using a different font internally to determine the spacing?

Here are the relevant code lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[nomath]{kpfonts}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,bibencoding=utf8,url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../literature/combined.bib}
...
\begin{document}
...
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}
\printbibliography
```

Who has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: my first try  would be \usepackage{microtype}.

Comment: I had not heard of microtype before, but it did the trick. All problems are solved.

How do I mark this question as solved when there is only a comment?

Comment: For more help on line breaks in the bibliography see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but `style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,` is equivalent to the shorter `style=numeric-comp,`. Usually `bibencoding=utf8,` is not needed, since the encoding can be inferred from the document (and you probably want to use UTF-8 for both the `.tex` and `.bib` file). You can (and should) remove `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` in favour of adding `heading=bibintoc` to the `\printbibliography` call: `\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]`. Usually I would put the `\setcounter` lines in the preamble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `\usepackage{microtype}`, it allows fonts to stretch a bit and so can often help in such cases.