# Biblatex is not performing linebreaks in certain situations

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I use the Overleaf online environment in order to write my dissertation. However, I noticed that several of my references in the bibliography are exceeding the allowed text width causing an incorrect line-break position. I have prepared a small example in order for you to recreate my issue.

1. My latex code

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}}
\usepackage[bibencoding=auto, sorting=none, babel=other, backend=biber, style=numeric, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames = 2, firstinits=true, url = false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography/Dissertation.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}

\section{Introduction}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam.
Test\cite{Muller2020}\cite{Bohn1988}.\cite{Mattiello2008b}\cite{Shen-long2017}\cite{Hippler2010, Tomberg2019}\cite{Miklos1989}\cite{Khamaganov2007}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

2. My bib entries

```
@phdthesis{Muller2020,
author = {M{\"{u}}ller, Max},
school = {OTH Regensburg},
title = {{Hard- und Softwareentwicklung eines Moduls zur Schallgeschwindigkeitsmessung in komplexen Gasgemischen bei 32 kHz}},
type = {M. Eng. thesis},
year = {2020}
}
@article{Bohn1988,
author = {Bohn, D A},
journal = {Journal of the Audio Engineering Society},
number = {4},
pages = {223--231},
title = {{Environmental effects on the speed of sound}},
volume = {36},
year = {1988}
}
@phdthesis{Mattiello2008b,
author = {Mattiello, Mario},
school = {University of Lausanne},
title = {{Gas Traces Measurement by Photoacoustic Spectroscopy Using Helmholtz Resonator-Based Sensors}},
type = {Ph. D. thesis},
year = {2008}
}
@article{Tomberg2019,
abstract = {Highly sensitive and selective trace gas detection based on a novel photo-acoustic laser spectroscopy method.},
author = {Tomberg, Teemu and Hieta, Tuomas and Vainio, Markku and Halonen, Lauri},
doi = {10.1039/C9AN00058E},
issn = {0003-2654},
journal = {The Analyst},
number = {7},
pages = {2291--2296},
title = {{Cavity-enhanced cantilever-enhanced photo-acoustic spectroscopy}},
url = {http://xlink.rsc.org/?DOI=C9AN00058E},
volume = {144},
year = {2019}
}
@article{Shen-long2017,
author = {Shen-long, ZHA and Kun, LIU and Tu, TAN and Gui-shi, WANG and Xiao-ming, GAO},
doi = {10.3788/gzxb20174606.0612002},
issn = {1004-4213},
journal = {ACTA PHOTONICA SINICA},
number = {6},
pages = {612002},
title = {{Application of Photoacoustic Spectroscopy in Multi-component Gas Concentration Detection}},
url = {http://www.opticsjournal.net/Abstract.htm?id=OJ170627000119D0GcJf},
volume = {46},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Miklos1989,
author = {Mikl{\'{o}}s, A. and L{\"{o}}rincz, A.},
doi = {10.1007/BF00694347},
issn = {0721-7269},
journal = {Applied Physics B Photophysics and Laser Chemistry},
month = {mar},
number = {3},
pages = {213--218},
title = {{Windowless resonant acoustic chamber for laser-photoacoustic applications}},
url = {http://link.springer.com/10.1007/BF00694347},
volume = {48},
year = {1989}
}
@article{Hippler2010,
author = {Hippler, Michael and Mohr, Christian and Keen, Katherine A. and McNaghten, Edward D.},
doi = {10.1063/1.3461061},
issn = {0021-9606},
journal = {The Journal of Chemical Physics},
month = {jul},
number = {4},
pages = {044308},
title = {{Cavity-enhanced resonant photoacoustic spectroscopy with optical feedback cw diode lasers: A novel technique for ultratrace gas analysis and high-resolution spectroscopy}},
url = {http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.3461061},
volume = {133},
year = {2010}
}
@article{Khamaganov2007,
author = {Khamaganov, V. and Karunanandan, R. and Rodriguez, A. and Crowley, J. N.},
doi = {10.1039/b701382e},
issn = {1463-9076},
journal = {Physical Chemistry Chemical Physics},
number = {31},
pages = {4098},
title = {{Photolysis of CH3C(O)CH3 (248 nm, 266 nm), CH3C(O)C2H5 (248 nm) and CH3C(O)Br (248 nm): pressure dependent quantum yields of CH3 formation}},
url = {http://xlink.rsc.org/?DOI=b701382e},
volume = {9},
year = {2007}
}
```

3. A picture of my result

[image]

I dont know what to do, to globally fix the issue of line-breaking in my bibliography. I would say 10% have an incorrect line-break. As you can see it is not always the title but sometimes the page or the DOI link.

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864

Comment: Specifically the bad line break in [1] is because your document is in English and LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate the German *Schallgeschwindigkeitsmessung* with English hyphenation patterns. In [3] LaTeX can't find a good line break in *Helmholtz*. In [4] the page number 612002 is an unbreakable chunk. In [6] the DOI is not breakable in a useful place. And in [7] LaTeX only allows *photo-acoustic* to break at the hyphen. My answer to the question I linked above should give specific advice for most of these problems as well as general hints for better line breaking in the bibliography.

Comment: Thank you for the link, so far I was able to solve all issues but the unbreakable "unknown/German" words. I guess I will manually edit the titles inserting valid linebreaks by my own in Mendeley (the tool I use for literature mangament).