# Bibliography - overfull hbox

Tags: pdftex, biber, biblatex-chicago

I am using [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/turabian-formatted-research-paper/drzcdssyhyqh) from Overleaf. I used the following packages to fix my overfull hbox errors:

```
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
```

Most of the URLs were then fixed, except for this one that still overflows:
[image]

The URL in question is `https://saanyan.github.io/saanmaycommunitypantry/`. It seems to be the only one that can't be broken.

Any and all advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The URL is too long to brake nicely. `\emergencystretch` may help here, but may have to stretch things too far. If you load `\usepackage{xurl}` URLs can break anywhere, which definitely improves this URL's line breaking.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 for a longer discussion on line breaking in the bibliography.

Comment: You haven't shown the code to reproduce the screenshot, so it is impossible to know what's going on, but the different indentation between the entries shown in the image looks a bit odd. You may want to verify that everything is as you expect and make sure TeX reports no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs can be really problematic for breaking and in your case you have a super-long word in the middle of a URL which doesn't allow for any good break points.

The best hope here is to tell LaTeX that lots of extra space is OK during the bibliography. Adding something like

```
\emergencystretch=1em
```

Before the bibliography will tell LaTeX that if it can't find a good breakpoint¹, it can add up to an extra em of space to try fixing line breaks. You may need to boost the size of `\emergencystretch`, but it will eventually fix your line break in the bibliography.

---

1. A lot of people will try to do things by adjusting `\tolerance` to allow sloppier line breaking (and this is exactly what `\sloppy` did historically, although it was changed to incorporate `\emergencystretch` at some point in the years after TeX 3.0 was released). I find that judicious use of `\emergencystretch` always produces better results.