# Overfull hbox in biblatex, how to insert line break between edition and publisher?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking, biber, overfull

I am trying to get my bibliography put together, and biblatex insists on not putting a line break where it seems like one makes sense. Here is my .bib file:

```
@book{paparudin,
title = {Real and complex analysis},
author = {Walter Rudin},
edition = {Third Edition},
series = {McGraw-Hill series in higher mathematics},
year = {1987},
publisher = {McGraw-Hill}
}

@book{babyrudin,
    title = {Principles of mathematical analysis},
    author = {Walter Rudin},
    edition = {Third Edition},
    series = {McGraw-Hill international editions},
    year = {1976},
    publisher = {McGraw-Hill}
}

@book{stein,
    title = {Fourier analysis - an introduction},
    author = {Elias M. Stein and Rami Shakarchi},
    series = {Princeton lectures in analysis},
    year = {2003},
    publisher = {Princeton University Press}
}
```

I have this in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
```

And I just have

```
\printbibliography
```

at the end of my document.

Problem is, my first citation compiles with an overfull hbox:

[image: bad hbox]

How do I fix this?

Comment: The specific cause of this is that TeX hyphenates words containing hyphens only at the hyphen and nowhere else. If other hyphenation points are acceptable, you can mark them with `\-`, so that TeX can hyphenate McGraw-Hill in more places. This may or may not help in this case. A number of possible options to get rid of bad line breaks in the bibliography are discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864.

Comment: Why doesn't it just send all of "McGraw-Hill" to the next line?

Comment: Because TeX prefers overfull boxes over underfull boxes. The linked Q&A also shows general ways to try and give TeX permission to make boxes more underfull (and thus send the unbreakable content to the next line).