# How to keep long words / numbers in bibliography entries within page margins

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking

I'm trying to make sure that bibliography entries stay within the margins of the page. But annoyingly, I get entries like this sometimes, where the DOI runs off the margin:

[image: bibliography]

Does anyone know a good way to stop this happening? Or whether there is something wrong with my code (quite possibly) ?

This is my code (simplified) :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, tmargin={1.75in}, bmargin={1.5in}, lmargin={1.25in}, rmargin={1.25in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{changepage}  

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't contain a single `\cite` directive or bib entry -- and hence cannot be used to replicate the problem you say you're experiencing. Please edit your query and post the bibtex code for the entry authored by Stedman.

Comment: Off-topic: I can't help but remark that the instruction `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}` looks, to put it delicately, a tad unusual. What's the purpose of eliminating all "leading" between lines? If what you mainly want to achieve is to keep footnote material from being rendered at a size that's about 20% smaller than the regular document font size, running `\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}` should do the trick.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 for more general hints on line breaking in the bibliography.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for that suggestion - I'm new to latex, so really have no idea what I'm doing right now

Comment: @moewe -- Great answer of yours in the link you provided. Regarding the passage "If you don't want to play around with the values of `biburlnumpenalty` etc. yourself and just want all URLs to break everywhere, you can load the `xurl` package": I'd give this passage *a lot* more visual prominence, in part because I doubt that many people have either the patience or the stomach to play around with `biburlnumpenalty` and friends. If you can make this adjustment, I'd be happy to close the present query as a duplicate. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you load the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package as well. Its purpose is to instruct LaTeX to allow line breaks to occur as needed at arbitrary locations inside URL strings and URL-like objects such as DOI strings that may occur in bibliographic entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{stedman,
   author   = "Richard C. Stedman",
   journal  = "Environment and behavior",
   title    = "Toward a Social Psychology of Place: 
               Predicting Behavior from Place-Based
               Cognitions, Attidude, and Identity",
   year     = 2002,
   month    = sep,
   volume   = 34,
   number   = 5,
   pages    = "561--581",
   issn     = "0013-9165",
   doi      = "10.1177/0013916502034005001",
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[a4paper, 
            tmargin=1.75in, bmargin=1.5in, 
            lmargin=1.25in, rmargin=1.25in]%
           {geometry}
           
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=black}

\usepackage{changepage}  

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, format=hang, 
              justification=raggedright, 
              singlelinecheck=false}
% \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

%%\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont} % huh??
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% \usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault\selectfont % mimic OP's screenshot
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked