# Bibliography doesnt match page set up

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting, overleaf

I'm having problem with a document in overleaf where my bibliography margins do not match the rest of the document (see attached). I need reference 4 to go onto the next line and respect the margins in the document.

My main page uses the following :

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib} %Import the bibliography file
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbding}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{XXXXXXXX}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{Page \thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{XXXXXX}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.59999pt}

\setlength\parindent{15pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}



\begin{document}

\input{titlepage}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents
```

if anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance .

Ross

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly `\usepackage{xurl}` would already solve this problem. If not then you should show the contents of the `.bib` file for this entry.

Comment: `xurl` looks like it should help here. For additional hints, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864. Note that we cannot test our recommendations, since we don't have your `.bib` entries, so that the code shown so far does not qualify as a compilable example document that reproduces the issue for us (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).