# Break line in bibliography for doi

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line

I generated a bibliography with biblatex. In one reference there seems to be a problem in splitting the Doi, so now the doi goes over the line on the right side. I tried solving this problem with different approaches that I found on this website but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{ProbelmLineBreacky,
    title = {{How to get a line breack}},
    year = {2019},
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {Smith and Mayer},
    number = {3},
    month = {9},
    pages = {69},
    volume = {7},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    url = {https://000000000},
    doi = {10.3390/something8838339},
    issn = {2227-9059},
    pmid = {31505812},
    keywords = {some}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,oneside]{memoir} 

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,filecolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue either, looks fine, can you edit in images as to how it looks and make your code show the issue please?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this but I added a picture of the reference concerned. DOes this help?

Comment: @mar123 I can't reproduce the problem with the code as it is in the question, but maybe try the `xurl` package?

Comment: @mar123 -- The example code in your question doesn't match the image.  If you change your example code to use the reference with the authors "Hannah Strobel et al.", that would be more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: As samcarter and barbara have mentioned the code posted does not reproduce the issue from the image, so it is hard to say anything with certainty. From the image it mostly looks like your problem is that your DOI contains an unbreakable sequence that is too long. You can allow breaks in the DOI (and URLs) everywhere with `\usepackage{xurl}`. Other options to improve the line breaking are discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xurl` package after `biblatex`.

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{ProbelmLineBreacky,
    title = {Title},
    year = {2019},
    journal = {Journal},
    author = {Smith},
    number = {3},
    pages = {69},
    volume = {7},
    doi = {10.3390/something8838339},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir} 

\usepackage[linkcolor=black,colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,filecolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl} % after biblatex
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]