# Manually breaking URL in bibliography adds ASCII characters

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, line-breaking, urls

I'm trying to break a URL in the bibliography. I used `\\`, thinking that it would solve the problem but while it broke the URL it also added the ASCII code for `\`.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtoolong.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{problematicentry}

\cite{problematicentry2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the bib file:

```
@online{problematicentry,
  title                     =   {{aaaaaaaaa}},
  organization              =   {bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb},
  url                       =   {https://cccccc.com/ddddddddd/eeee/ffff/gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg/hhh/iiiiiiii/jjjjjjjjjj},
  date                      =   {2023-07-22}
}

@online{problematicentry2,
  title                     =   {{aaaaaaaaa}},
  organization              =   {bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb},
  url                       =   {https://cccccc.com/ddddddddd/eeee/ffff/\\gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg/hhh/iiiiiiii/jjjjjjjjjj},
  date                      =   {2023-07-22}
}
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to prevent the characters from appearing while manually breaking the URL?

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442317/2388 for various strategies with long urls and bibliographies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{fullpage}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xurl}
\addbibresource{bibtoolong.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{problematicentry}

\cite{problematicentry2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It solved my problem but `xurl` must be added after `biblatex`