# Best practices in Biblatex bibliography hyphenation

Tags: biblatex

What are the best practices for having correct hyphenation in the bibliography section of documents when using Biblatex? Most times my bibliography seems wrongly formatted, especially in two-column documents. URLs and names with a hyphen are also difficult to deal with.

Comment: For urls, have a look at the `xurl` package.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864

Comment: @moewe Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you, I will take a look at this.

Comment: I guess the best match to the general question that we have is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864. But since the problem is pretty common and can have a wide range of causes, you may need other solutions in your specific case. In that case I suggest you ask a new question with a useful MWE.